# Laravel Eloquent - Filter Relationship of Relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

This is the query I tried to do:

```
$products = Product::with(['cross_selling.product_related' => 
   fn($query) => $query->where('status_id', '=', '2')])
  ->where('status_id',2)
  ->get();
```

I get this results:

[image]

In cross_selling I still get id:12 that doesn't has any product_related. I need some help for making that the query doesn't give me that item if product_related is null.

Tks.

Comment: `$this->filteredSql`?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, edited! Tks for notice.

Comment: Please post models relations and scheme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First get only those cross selling which has any related products after that get related products. Use the `whereHas` condition on cross_selling.

```
$products = Product::with(['cross_selling' => function($qry){
    $qry->whereHas('product_related', function ($q) {
        $q->where('status_id', 2);
    });
    }, 'cross_selling.product_related' =>
    fn($query) => $query->where('status_id', '=', '2')])
    ->where('status_id',2)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Tks you very much @Karnal-YK, this was the perfect solution!

Comment: Hi @Fryla-CristianMarucci , I am new on stackoverflow. It is showing 50 bounty points but I didn't get yet. Do you know anything about it?

Comment: @Karnal-YK https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Comment: In two days from today you'll get it !

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$products = Product::with(['cross_selling.product_related' => 
   fn($query) => $query->where('status_id', '=', '2')])
  ->has('cross_selling.product_related')
  ->where('status_id',2)
  ->get();
```

Comment: Not working, same result.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want cross selling products with no related products you can add

```
->whereHas('product_related')
```

Which basically says: Get me only cross selling which have 'product_related'.

In order to do it properly, you can:

```
$callback = fn($query) => $query->where('status_id', 2);
$products = Product::whereHas('cross_selling.product_related', $callback)
->with(['cross_selling.product_related' => $callback])
->where('status_id',2)->get();
```

Now the callback is applied to the `whereHas()` and the `with()` plus you can pass additional constraints using $callback.

Comment: Not working, same result here too. Tks anyway.